Best Practices for Frontend User Auth and Data Fetching with Supabase
I'm currently building a web application using Supabase as the backend and Nuxt as frontend and am looking for advice on how to handle user authentication and data retrieval on the frontend securely and efficiently. I'm currently doing everything (except login) with Nitro (Nuxt.js server); so data retrieval, registration, etc.
Is this really necessary or can I make this easier with Row Level Security?
